# Combine sparse and masked array in numpy

Tags: numpy, sparse-matrix

Is there a convenient way to use masked array over sparse matrices ?

Because it seems that mask not work when creating masked array with scipy sparse matrix...

And a typical application would be a adjacency matrix where values could be {0,1,?} for representing links in a network {0,1} and unknown/unseen value {?} to predict.

Comment: the docs http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html mention that some operations might have side effects. What about using `numpy.ma.filled` to turn the masked array into a normal one based on the mask and the fill value?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not surprised that trying to give a sparse matrix to masked does not work.  The few `numpy` functions that work with sparse ones are ones that delegate to the task to the sparse code.

It might be possible to construct a `coo` format matrix with the `data` attribute being a masked array, but I doubt if that carries far.  Code that isn't `masked` aware generally will ignore the mask.

A masked array is an `ndarray` subclass that maintains two attributes, the data and mask, both of which are arrays.  Many masked methods work by filling the masked values with a suitable value (0 for sums, 1 for products), and performing regular array calculations.

A sparse matrix is not an `ndarray` subclass.  One format is actually a dictionary subclass.  Most store their data in 3 arrays, the 2 coordinates and the data.  Interactions with non-sparse arrays often involve `todense()` to turn the action into a regular `numpy` one.

There's no interoperability by design.  If something does work it's probably because of some coincidental delegation of method.

For example

```
In [85]: A=sparse.coo_matrix(np.eye(3))
In [86]: M=np.ma.masked_array(np.eye(3))
In [87]: A+M
Out[87]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[ 2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  2.]],
             mask =
 False,
       fill_value = 1e+20)

In [88]: M+A
NotImplementedError: adding a nonzero scalar to a sparse matrix is not supported
```

I would have expected `M+A` to work, but since I read it as adding sparse to a masked.  But sometimes `x+y` is actually implemented as `y.__add__(x)`. `A+np.eye(3)` works in both orders.